# Finding the maximum area of polygon?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Firstly , I divided the polygon to three triangles and I used the  Heron's formula to find the area of triangles which formed the polygon $$A=\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$$.I couldn't  find easily the relationship between $d$ and area for the three triangles.  Now I need the distance $d$ which give me a maximum area of polygon.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

$$ h1=\sqrt{5^2-(\frac{d}{2})^2} \\$$upper triangle area is $$ s1=\frac{1}{2}d\sqrt{5^2-(\frac{d}{2})^2}$$
$$h2=\sqrt{4^2-(\frac{d-5}{2})^2}\\$$so 2 lower triangle area =$$s2=2*\frac{1}{2}\frac{d-5}{2}\sqrt{4^2-(\frac{d-5}{2})^2} $$ rectangle area is =$$s3=5*\sqrt{4^2-(\frac{d-5}{2})^2} $$the problem reduce to max s=s1+s2+s3
$$s_{total}=s1+s2+s3=s1=\frac{1}{2}d\sqrt{5^2-(\frac{d}{2})^2}+2*\frac{1}{2}\frac{d-5}{2}\sqrt{4^2-(\frac{d-5}{2})^2}+ 5*\sqrt{4^2-(\frac{d-5}{2})^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Of use is [Brahmagupta's Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula) $A=\sqrt{(s-a)(s-b)(s-c)(s-d)}$ where $s=(a+b+c+d)/2$ which describes the area of cyclic quadrilaterals.  Trapezoids of the type shown as the bottom part of the pentagon, with both slanted edges the same, called [isosceles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isosceles_trapezoid), are all cyclic.